# Python. Selenium. How to wait for new window opens?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a button with twitter, and after click new window opens, but before opening there is a timout in few seconds, so is there a way to wait for it? I mait in a bad way for now...

```
    Ui.click_el(link.W9FormNodes.TWITTER_BUTTON)
    # Wait for new window and switch to it
    time.sleep(3)
    aw = driver.window_handles
    driver.switch_to_window(aw[1])
```

So I need something better, that will wait only that amount of seconds that needs.

I think I solve it in this way. But maybe someone will have comments how to do it better.

```
    aw = Ui.click_and_wait_for_window(link.W9FormNodes.TWITTER_BUTTON)
    driver.switch_to_window(aw[1])
```

And here is a method that click on button and wait for new window:

```
    def click_and_wait_for_window(self, node):
        current_value = old_value = self.driver.window_handles
        self.click_el(node)
        while len(current_value) == len(old_value):
            time.sleep(0.05)
            current_value = self.driver.window_handles
        return current_value
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Surya mentioned, `WebDriverWait` would be the way to wait for a change. You could have a context manager like this that **only** implements the wait logic and then use it for any kind of operation you care about:

```
@contextmanager
def wait_for_new_window(driver, timeout=10):
    handles_before = driver.window_handles
    yield
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
        lambda driver: len(handles_before) != len(driver.window_handles))
```

Here's a full working example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def wait_for_new_window(driver, timeout=10):
    handles_before = driver.window_handles
    yield
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
        lambda driver: len(handles_before) != len(driver.window_handles))

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://www.google.com")

with wait_for_new_window(driver):
    driver.execute_script("""
    window.open("http://www.google.com", "_blank");
    """)

with wait_for_new_window(driver, 2):
    pass # This will obviously hit the timeout.

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Just to clarify. lambda driver: is waiting until condition in it will satisfied? And also can you tell me what is "yield" and "with"?

Comment: Yes. If if the `lambda` evaluates to a true value, this means the condition is satisfied and the wait ends. If it evaluates to a false value, then the wait continues (as long as the timeout limit is not met).

Comment: Already implement this wait. Works really great! Thank you! A bit complex for me with "with" and "yield" so I just take that condition for lambda driver:. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Now there has a function in the `selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions` package. For example:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
WebDriverWait(web, 20).until(EC.new_window_is_opened(driver.window_handles))
```

It will wait for the new window opens.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; your implementation looks fine. Only thing is you need to set the timeout, otherwise it will wait for ever, if new window doesn't open.

You can combine with `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until..` to set the timeout.
Hope this helps.