# python selenium webdriver open new window handle wait

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

When I click a button open new window 
How do I know window open finished?

In wait frame can I use below

```
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_name('newframe')))
```

in new window?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the count of the current(before) window handles and get after windows handles and implement `lambda` to wait for them **NOT** to be equal. I am not familiar with such/similar build in `Selenium` mechanism.

```
def wait_for_new_window(driver, timeout=10):
        handles_before = driver.window_handles
        yield
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
            lambda driver: len(handles_before) != len(driver.window_handles))
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641779/python-selenium-how-to-wait-for-new-window-opens) on similar topic.