# Python 3.5 - Selenium - How to handle a new window and wait until it is fully loaded?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser, webdriver

I am doing browser automation and I am blocked at a certain point: at a moment, I ask the browser to click on a button, which in turn open up a new window. But sometimes the Internet is too slow, and so this new window takes time to load. I want to know how can I ask Selenium to wait until this new fresh window is fully loaded.

Here's my code:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
Button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'addPicturesBtn')))
Button.click()
newWindow = driver.window_handles
time.sleep(5)
newNewWindow = newWindow[1]
driver.switch_to.window(newNewWindow)
newButtonToLoad = driver.find_element_by_id('d')
newButtonToLoad.send_keys('pic.jpg')
uploadButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'uploadPics')))
uploadButton.click()
driver.switch_to.window(newWindow[0])
```

I get this error from time to time:

> newNewWindow = newWindow[1]
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

which make me think that a simple 'time.sleep(5)' doesn't do the work.

**So, my question is, how can I wait until this new window is fully loaded before interacting with it?**

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to use following code to wait until new window appears:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
```

Your code should looks like

```
Button.click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))

newWindow = driver.window_handles
newNewWindow = newWindow[1]
driver.switch_to.window(newNewWindow)
```

Considering @JimEvans comment, try below:

```
current = driver.window_handles[0]
Button.click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))

newWindow = [window for window in driver.window_handles if window != current][0]
driver.switch_to.window(newWindow)
```

Comment: I'll point out here that this code suffers from the common fallacy of assuming the window handle list returned by `window_handles` is ordered. It is not. In other words, with two window handles, `window_handles[0]` may not be the first one opened, and `window_handles[1]` may not be the last one opened.

Comment: @JimEvans can you elaborate a little more? I mean, that may cause future problems, so how solve the problem you're pointing out?

Comment: @JimEvans, Please, do not confuse OP using comments about `this code` :) Mentioned flaw present in initial code provided in question and I re-use it just to point out were to insert my solution.. However, answer updated to solve list order issue of `window_handles`

Comment: searched for long and only this answer worked especially comment by @JimEvans is life saver.

Comment: @Andersson, I'm getting `WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(1))
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'number_of_windows_to_be'`.
Any hack for this?

Answer (score 1):

What I'm using:

```
windows = set(driver.window_handles)
driver.execute_script("window.open()")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.new_window_is_opened(windows))
hwnd = list(set(driver.window_handles) - windows)[0]
```

You can create a function or a context manager [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26648414/3754432) for it if you find it necessary, but for essentially 3 lines (not counting the one that actually opens the window, which may be very different for each case), I prefer to just copy-paste.

To be thorough, here's a feature-enriched alternative:

```
@contextmanager
def wait_for_new_window(driver, timeout=10, switch=True):
    """Waits for a new window to open

    Parameters:
        driver: WebDriver.
            Selenium WebDriver object.
        timeout: int
            Maximum waiting time
        switch: bool
            If `True` (default), switches to the window.


    Exemplo:
        >>> with wait_for_new_window(driver) as hwnds:
        ...     driver.execute_script("window.open()");
        ... print("Window opened:", hwnds[0])
    """
    windows = set(driver.window_handles)
    handle = []
    yield handle
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.new_window_is_opened(windows))
    hwnds = list(set(driver.window_handles) - windows)
    handle.extend(hwnds)
    if switch:
        driver.switch_to.window(hwnds[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

The exact answer for  waiting **a NEW window** to be **fully loaded**  is:

using **`url_changes`** from `expected_conditions` with the old URL parameter as *"about:blank"*   :

```
WebDriverWait(Driver, 15).until(EC.url_changes("about:blank"))
```

A sample code might look like:

```
        ...
        # Wait till a new window opened (2nd window in this example)
        WebDriverWait(Driver, 15).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))

        # Switch to second window
        window_after = Driver.window_handles[1]
        Driver.switch_to.window(window_after)

        # Wait till **new window fully loaded**:
        WebDriverWait(Driver, 15).until(EC.url_changes("about:blank"))
        ...
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as this answer covers the new tab's loading time, too.