# How to access the outerfunction while breaking from inner function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have developed following code. Normally it works fine. But, sometimes while downloading the records (record()), it fails as server fails to respond or if internet is disconnected. To avoid breaking of code I used 'try-exceptions' but then, I can not break out from record() as well as outer function simultaneously. So, looking for solution. Code around 197th line doesn't help in continuing the code from outer while loop. Code is here:

```
import glob
import datetime
import cv2
import base64
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import time
import selenium
import self as self
from pytesseract import pytesseract
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC, expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException, StaleElementReferenceException, \
    WebDriverException, ElementNotInteractableException, UnexpectedAlertPresentException

main_Directory = r'/home/sangharshmanuski/Documents/e_courts/mha/downloads4'
log_Directory = r'/home/sangharshmanuski/Documents/e_courts/mha/log'
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
url = r'https://districts.ecourts.gov.in/'
driver.get(url)
# create wait time variable for regular, short and mid
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 180)
waitShort = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#sateist > option:nth-child(22)")))
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#sateist'))
options = select.options
select.select_by_visible_text('Maharashtra')
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.region')))

    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#sateist')))
    districtListDropdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#sateist"))
    distOptions = districtListDropdown.options

    # iterate over each district
    i = 1
    while i < len(distOptions):
        try:
            wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#sateist')))
            newDistDropDown = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#sateist"))
        except:
            continue
        newDistOptions = newDistDropDown.options
        distName = newDistOptions[i].text
        print(distName)
        newDistDropDown.select_by_index(i)
        # for creating directory as per each district.
        district_directory = os.path.join(
            main_Directory, distName)  # create new
        if not os.path.exists(district_directory):  # if not directory exists, create one
            os.mkdir(district_directory)
        district_log_directory = os.path.join(log_Directory, distName)
        if not os.path.exists(district_log_directory):  # if not directory exists, create one
            os.mkdir(district_log_directory)
        headingDist = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.heading')
        if headingDist.text.lower() == distName.lower():
            wait.until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.accordion2:nth-child(2)'))).click()
            current = driver.window_handles[0]
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                 'div.panel:nth-child(3) > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(6) > a:nth-child(1)'))).click()
            # wait until new tab opens.
            wait.until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
            # define new tab by differentiating from current tab.
            newWindow = [window for window in driver.window_handles if window != current][0]
            # switch to the new tab. ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571217/python-3-5-selenium-how-to-handle-a-new-window-and-wait-until-it-is-fully-lo
            driver.switch_to.window(newWindow)
            # wait till court complex list appears.
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#court_complex_code')))
            # create list of all court complex.
            # 2 approaches - 1 select 2 click.
            time.sleep(3)


            def complex_and_act():
                this = driver.current_window_handle

                def imgtotxt():
                    elem = driver.find_element_by_id("captcha_image")
                    loc = elem.location
                    size = elem.size
                    left = loc['x']
                    top = loc['y']
                    width = size['width']
                    height = size['height']
                    box = (int(left), int(top), int(left + width), int(top + height))
                    screenshot = driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
                    img = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(screenshot)))
                    area = img.crop(box)
                    area.save('/home/sangharshmanuski/Documents/e_courts/captcha/file_trial.png', 'PNG')
                    fullPath = r'/home/sangharshmanuski/Documents/e_courts/captcha'
                    f = os.listdir(fullPath)
                    desPath = r"/home/sangharshmanuski/Documents/e_courts/editC"
                    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(fullPath, 'file_trial.png'), 0)
                    ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img, 111, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
                    cv2.imwrite('/home/sangharshmanuski/Documents/e_courts/editC/oneDisNoLoop.png', thresh1)
                    # know the text with pytesseract
                    captchaText = pytesseract.image_to_string(
                        Image.open('/home/sangharshmanuski/Documents/e_courts/editC/oneDisNoLoop.png'))
                    captcha = driver.find_element_by_id('captcha')
                    captcha.send_keys(captchaText)
                    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.button:nth-child(1)').click()
                    time.sleep(1)

                def proceed():
                    while True:
                        try:
                            waitShort.until(EC.alert_is_present())
                            driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
                            driver.switch_to.window(this)
                            driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
                                '#captcha_container_2 > div:nth-child('
                                '1) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(7) > img:nth-child(1)').click()
                            log_file = open(os.path.join(log_Directory, nameCourtComp + '.txt'), 'a')
                            log_file.write('alert was present' + '\n')
                            print('alert was present')
                            imgtotxt()
                        except:
                            # if the waitmsg is on, wait for 5 sec
                            log_file = open(os.path.join(log_Directory, nameCourtComp + '.txt'), 'a')
                            log_file.write('no alert' + '\n')
                            print('no alert')
                            waitmsg = 0
                            while driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#waitmsg').is_displayed():
                                if waitmsg < 7:
                                    log_file = open(
                                        os.path.join(log_Directory, nameCourtComp + '.txt'), 'a')
                                    log_file.write('wait' + '\n')
                                    print('waitmsg')
                                    time.sleep(1)
                                    waitmsg += 1
                                else:
                                    log_file = open(os.path.join(
                                        log_Directory, nameCourtComp + '.txt'), 'a')
                                    log_file.write('waiting finished' + '\n')
                                    print('waiting finished')
                                    break
                            invalidCaptcha = "Invalid Captcha"
                            norecord = "Record Not Found"
                            try:
                                waitShort.until(
                                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#errSpan > p:nth-child(1)')))
                                incorrect = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#errSpan > p:nth-child(1)').text
                                if incorrect == invalidCaptcha:
                                    log_file = open(
                                        os.path.join(log_Directory, nameCourtComp + '.txt'), 'a')
                                    log_file.write('Invalid Captcha' + '\n')
                                    print('invalid captcha')
                                    imgtotxt()
                                    continue
                                else:
                                    if incorrect == norecord:
                                        log_file = open(
                                            os.path.join(log_Directory, nameCourtComp + '.txt'), 'a')
                                        log_file.write('Record not Found' + '\n')
                                        return print('record not found')

                            except:
                                pass

                            def record():
                                log_file = open(
                                    os.path.join(log_Directory, nameCourtComp + '.txt'), 'a')
                                log_file.write('Record Found' + '\n')
                                print('record fun started')
                                wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.someclass')))
                                listAllView = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
                                    'a.someclass')
                                # make new dirctory by name of Court Complex
                                distDir2 = os.path.join(
                                    main_Directory, distName, nameCourtComp)
                                if not os.path.exists(distDir2):
                                    os.makedirs(distDir2)
                                x = 0
                                for view in listAllView:
                                    try:
                                        view.click()
                                        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'back_top')))
                                        openFile = open(
                                            os.path.join(distDir2, "file_" + str(x) + ".html"), "w")
                                        openFile.write(driver.page_source)
                                        openFile.close()
                                        back = driver.find_element_by_id('back_top')
                                        back.click()
                                        x += 1
                                    except (TimeoutException, ElementNotInteractableException):

                                        driver.refresh()
                                        log_file = open(
                                            os.path.join(log_Directory, nameCourtComp + '.txt'), 'a')
                                        log_file.write(
                                            'While Downloading record for '
                                            + nameCourtComp + ' error occured, retrying now...' + '\n')
                                        nonlocal courtComp
                                        courtComp -= 1
                                        return print(
                                            'While Downloading record for '
                                            + nameCourtComp + ' error occured, retrying now...')
                                log_file = open(
                                    os.path.join(log_Directory, nameCourtComp + '.txt'), 'a')
                                log_file.write('record completed, ' + str(x) + ' records found' + '\n')
                                print('record completed, ' + str(x) + ' records found')
                                return

                            record()
                            return
                courtComp = 1
                courtComplexDownload = Select(
                    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#court_complex_code'))
                courtComplexDownloadList = courtComplexDownload.options
                courtComplexLen = len(courtComplexDownloadList)
                while courtComp < courtComplexLen:
                    nameCourtComp = courtComplexDownloadList[courtComp].text
                    log_file = open(os.path.join(log_Directory, nameCourtComp + '.txt'), 'w')
                    log_file.write(nameCourtComp + '\n' + '\n')
                    print(nameCourtComp)
                    courtComplexDownload.select_by_index(courtComp)
                    acts = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#actcode'))
                    actsOpt = acts.options
                    act = 0
                    while len(actsOpt) < 2:
                        if act < 10:

                            time.sleep(1)
                            act += 1
                        else:
                            #if there is no list to populate break out of this loop & go to next complex
                            raise Exception()
                    try:
                        acts.select_by_value('33')
                    except NoSuchElementException:
                        print('PoA not applicable')
                        log_file = open(
                            os.path.join(log_Directory, nameCourtComp + '.txt'), 'a')
                        log_file.write('No PoA' + '\n')
                        courtComp += 1
                        continue

                    imgtotxt()
                    proceed()
                    courtComp += 1


            complex_and_act()
            driver.close()
            print("all court complexes in " + distName + " completed")
            driver.switch_to.window(current)
            driver.back()

        else:
            time.sleep(5)
            continue
        i += 1

    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#sateist > option:nth-child(22)")))
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#sateist'))
    options = select.options
    select.select_by_visible_text('Maharashtra')
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.region')))
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#sateist')))
```

Comment: It would help if you posted a [smaller bit of code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us understand the issue. It sounds like you're handling the exception too early. Have you tried just handling the exception in the outer function where you want to break/continue?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what exceptions are for.  Whenever you raise an exception, it's going to go to the containing scope, and if that scope doesn't catch it, it'll stop whatever it's doing and the exception will go up to the next scope, et cetera.  It's a very easy way to make sure that if something goes wrong, you can break out of multiple levels of loop or multiple levels of function call without having to have each level check a return value.

When you swallow an exception, as you're doing here:

```
except (TimeoutException, ElementNotInteractableException):
    ...
    return print(
         'While Downloading record for '
         + nameCourtComp + ' error occured, retrying now...')
```

you're thwarting that process.  (Note that you're returning `None`, so the caller gets no information whatsoever!)  Instead, maybe do something like:

```
except (TimeoutException, ElementNotInteractableException):
    ...
    print(
         'While Downloading record for '
         + nameCourtComp + ' error occured, retrying now...')
    raise
```

The `raise` will just re-raise the same exception up to the next level, where they can do their own handling.  Alternatively, you could create your own exception (maybe with more information) and raise that instead; it's completely valid to catch an exception and then raise a different type of exception as a way of translating it for the caller.