# Selenium No Element Found Exception even after copying element from source code

Tags: html, selenium, exception

I am trying to simply login to this page to access LexisNexis. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
type(browser)

browser.get('https://sfx.carli.illinois.edu/sfxuiu?url_ver=Z39.88-2004&url_ctx_fmt=infofi/fmt:kev:mtx:ctx&ctx_enc=info:ofi/enc:UTF-8&ctx_ver=Z39.88-2004&rfr_id=info:sid/sfxit.com:azlist&sfx.ignore_date_threshold=1&rft.object_id=63750000000001351&svc.fulltext=yes')
linkElem2 = browser.find_element_by_link_text('LEXIS NEXIS DATABASES') 
type(linkElem2)
linkElem2.click()
alert = browser.switch_to.alert
alert.accept()

loginElem = browser.find_element_by_id('j_username')
loginElem.send_keys('username')
passElem = browser.find_element_by_id('j_password')
passElem.send_keys('password')
passElem.submit()
```

And here is the html source:

```
div class="form_row"

label for="j_username"
Enter your strongNetID:/strong/label

input id="j_username" name="j_username" autocomplete="OFF" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" value="" type="text"
/div
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Problem**
"LEXIS NEXIS DATABASES" link open new window and you have to switch to it to login, [Handle multiple windows in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629815/handle-multiple-windows-in-python):

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
browser.implicitly_wait(5)

browser.get('https://sfx.carli.illinois.edu/sfxuiu?url_ver=Z39.88-2004&url_ctx_fmt=infofi/fmt:kev:mtx:ctx&ctx_enc=info:ofi/enc:UTF-8&ctx_ver=Z39.88-2004&rfr_id=info:sid/sfxit.com:azlist&sfx.ignore_date_threshold=1&rft.object_id=63750000000001351&svc.fulltext=yes')
browser.find_element_by_link_text('LEXIS NEXIS DATABASES').click()

browser.close()
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[0])

browser.find_element_by_id('j_username').send_keys('username')
passElem = browser.find_element_by_id('j_password')
passElem.send_keys('password')
passElem.submit()
```

**2. Problem** [Link](https://compass2g.illinois.edu/webapps/login/) you share in comments is have error when you open for the first time(new browser profile).
[image] 
All you need is open [page](https://compass2g.illinois.edu/webapps/login/) and click "Login with your Illinois NetID" to open login page successfully. This way much better, because you don't need to handle windows, check code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
browser.implicitly_wait(5)

browser.get('https://compass2g.illinois.edu/webapps/login/')
browser.find_element_by_link_text('Login with your Illinois NetID').click()

browser.implicitly_wait(5)

browser.find_element_by_id('j_username').send_keys('username')
passElem = browser.find_element_by_id('j_password')
passElem.send_keys('password')
passElem.submit()
```

Comment: Still not working :/ I even ran the exact code from the book automate the boring stuff, the one to login to email, and it gives the same error! Element not found!!

Comment: Provide url or html

Comment: Check if inputs inside iframe tag

Comment: https://shibboleth.illinois.edu/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO?execution=e1s1

Comment: Great! This helped a lot!!!!! I had to change the passElem line to look like the browser.find_element_by_id line, but that was it. Thanks again, I spent HOURS trying to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on that link opens a new tab, so you need to switch to new tab before locating username and password fields. Try this (indentation may be broken):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
browser.get('https://sfx.carli.illinois.edu/sfxuiu?url_ver=Z39.88-2004&url_ctx_fmt=infofi/fmt:kev:mtx:ctx&ctx_enc=info:ofi/enc:UTF-8&ctx_ver=Z39.88-2004&rfr_id=info:sid/sfxit.com:azlist&sfx.ignore_date_threshold=1&rft.object_id=63750000000001351&svc.fulltext=yes')
linkElem2 = browser.find_element_by_link_text('LEXIS NEXIS DATABASES') 
linkElem2.click()
alert = browser.switch_to.alert  
alert.accept()
time.sleep(5) #to add 5 sec wait, you can use other wait methods for window handle. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641779/python-selenium-how-to-wait-for-new-window-opens
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'j_username')))
loginElem = browser.find_element_by_id('j_username')
loginElem.send_keys('username')
passElem = browser.find_element_by_id('j_password')
passElem.send_keys('password')
passElem.submit()
```

you will need following imports

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you! I am still getting errors though. first it said name 'driver' not defined, so I used browser instead. Then it said list index out of range, so I changed it to 0. Then it says name 'wait' not defined, so I used:

Comment: from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

Comment: correct, You will need imports for wait method, please see my updated answer

Comment: I used the imports, but I keep getting Timeout Exception. I tried 10,20,30,60 but still not working :/

Comment: I am not sure if this means it still can't find the element. Maybe the element is hidden? But I am not sure how to make it so that python can find it!!

Comment: No, its not hidden. Are you accepting alert? I was trying in chrome earlier and now I just tried in FF and found that you have to accept alert. Can you try with that?

Comment: Yup, accepting alert and also not switching tabs because that gave me an error

Comment: No, you will have to switch to a different tab, try my updated answer again.

Comment: Just tried it, getting this error: browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1]) #// to switch to new tab

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: instead of browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1]) can you try browser.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1]) // this would get the lastest window. Also, try to add some wait before searching for new tab

Comment: yes, it did. It was just a matter of adding some wait before searching for new tab as I mentioned in my above comment. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Now I am getting this error: ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

Comment: This is part of the output I see:
File "/Users/danashaat/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()

  File "/Users/danashaat/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")

  File "/Users/danashaat/anaconda/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)

ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

Comment: It doesn't show me exactly which line is producing this error but I do get to the login page before getting the error

Comment: none of the code you posted in error is in the stack trace. The problem in your code where ever you are using read() method.

Comment: I don't really know what that means!!